# Up arrow key for history not working in zsh and iTerm (MacOS)

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm

For the last few weeks I've been unable to use the up and down arrow keys to navigate my command history in zsh.

I'm using the following:

- Intel MacBook Pro with macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)
- zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)
- iTerm 3.4.2
- oh my zsh (latest master)

I tried a few solutions from existing answers but I couldn't find a way to make it work.
Here is some output from commands related to the issue:

Read and pressing the up arrow key

```
$ read
^[[A
```

Bindkey

```
$ bindkey | grep up-line
"^[OA" up-line-or-beginning-search
"^[[5~" up-line-or-history
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
```

Related variables

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/mac/.zsh_history
```

```
$ echo $SAVEHIST
10000
```

```
$ ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw-------  1 mac  staff  74285 Dec  3 14:57 /Users/mac/.zsh_history
```

Changing the binding to `up-line-or-search` didn't seem to help.

Not exactly sure where else to look and where this problem might originate. Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change settings in iTerm -> settings -> terminal -> terminal emulation-> report terminal type -> to xterm.

[iTerm Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv06x.png)

Comment: Worked for me.  Mine was previously set to "xterm256-color" which was working fine until a recent update (which is basically whenever you open iTerm).  Colors still showing with "xterm".  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> > Bell Icon/ring means an error (History has been disabled on this host). You can type history to validate that you don't get any output.